# ignore missing(empty) variable values in survfit function in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I'm performing a survival models by survfit package in R for a set of files and taking into account a vector of variables. Bellow i show an example input with the variables to perform the survival curves.

```
record_id   time    event   variable1   variable2
A   5   1   x1  y1
B   7   0   x2  
C   12  0   x3  y2
D   7   1       y3
F   8   1   x4  y4
```

And so on... However there are NA values in some rows corresponding to variables 1 and 2 and i would like to ignore the "NA survival curve" when the survival curves are performed for each variable since there are **five** curves (in this example that i show), four corresponding to variables x and y and another one corresponding to empty class in each case and i want to ignore the empty class. I'm try to adding `"na.omit"` either in survfit function and inside the ggsurvplot command without success. On the other hand I'm try too put some formula on input files to taking into account only the values `!is.na` applied on the inputs. Note that the script shown bellow is a simplified version and designed to take a set of files. Furthermore i generate one .tiff image for each file.

```
files=c(file1,file2)
variables=c(variable1,variable2)

for (k in 1:length(files)){
     for(i in 1:length(variables)){
         tables[[k]]<-read.csv(files[k], header = T,sep = "\t", dec =".")
         fit[[k]] <- survfit(as.formula(paste0("Surv(time, event) ~", variables[i])),
                 data = tables[[k]])
  file_curve = paste(substr(files[k]),"_",variables[i],".tiff", sep="")
  tiff(file_curve)
print(
ggsurvplot(fit[[k]])
dev.off()
```

In summary i would like to obtain the survival curves only for the classes included into the variables ignoring the "empty class" in the variables.
Are there some ways to get it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the `survival` `survfit` function the missing values are not plotted
see the first plot. this function do not create a strata for missing cases

I think you have an empty string  if the data is missing like in the second plot.
In that case you have to replace them with `NA`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

lung1=lung%>%
  mutate(wt.loss= case_when(wt.loss>20 ~ "high",
                            wt.loss>0 ~ "mild",
                            wt.loss<0 ~ NA))

fit=survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ wt.loss, data = lung1)
ggsurvplot(fit)
```

[image]

```r
lung2=lung%>%
  mutate(wt.loss= case_when(wt.loss>20 ~ "high",
                            wt.loss>0 ~ "mild",
                            wt.loss<0 ~ ""))
sum(is.na(lung$wt.loss))
#> [1] 14
fit=survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ wt.loss, data = lung2)
ggsurvplot(fit)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wael. Your answer has been useful. In mi case due to the variables x and y are not numeric i added: `tables[[k]]<-tables[[k]]%>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.,"")))` and it works. Anyway is the same intention that you mentioned above. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help,Exactly ``na_if`` is a better solution in your case. in my demo i transformed the ``wt.loss`` from numeric to character one. the aim is to reproduce your problem with an available database in r with some hints.